# How to make the OAuth 2.0 plugin work on Kong

Tags: oauth-2.0, kong

I am new to Kong and microservice. I am using Kong CE version 0.14.1 and I need to secure an existing API through Oauth2.0 plugin.
I tried to follow the instructions in the documentation  [kong-oauth2-hello-world](https://github.com/Kong/kong-oauth2-hello-world) provided by Kong.
The problem is when I click on the Authorize button, I always get [undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2bWt.png). I don't get the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXPHP.png) that provides the token like the documentation.
I think I missed something or I misunderstood the instraction.
Here [the environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b34Dq.png) I used by the Node.js application.

 Could anyone help me understand the reason why I get undefined  ?
Thank you

Comment: Please follow these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

I just replaced "openweathermap.org" with "mockbin.org" and it works fine